# avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00

Tags: arduino-uno

So I try to compile and upload a simple code such as the Basic Blink.
I have not connected it to pin 0 or pin 1.

There is an LED with the "L" label on the card that works. So I guess not the chip is damaged?

I have selected the correct model which is Arduino Uno / Genuino. I've checked the drivers several times now, even reinstalled Arduino Software twice and tried on 2 different computers.

5V works with ground, I can get the LED to light up. But I cannot compile / upload code.

```
Error MSG: avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
(this message repeats 10 times with attempts)
```

I read something about bootloader, but I have no idea how to do this / what it is. I do not have the right components for bootloading I guess.

Also the COM is correct. I've tried using all the listed COMs without any result. Is this a hardware issue? Is my chip grilled or something?

Comment: That might be a bootloader issue, it is not hard to solve but you will need another arduino as programmer to reprogram the bootloader.

Comment: But the L led is working? If that one works, shouldn't the chip be working? By the way, how do I remove the chip?

Comment: Ah sorry, if the LED marked L ( usually known as pin 13 ) is on, then it might be another problem, since the booloader is still there. did you unplug any circuit attached to Arduino on upload time?

Comment: How to remove the chip? watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hi5CsIsq28M

Comment: https://youtu.be/P6IKJehtB_c . Bad quality, but this is how it looks.

Comment: According to the video, your bootloader is still there and the reset works just fine, so the microcontroller is working. I see your TX LED constantly on ?!

Comment: TX led is flashing rapidly fast. Looks like it is sending all the time, is this normal?

Comment: No, there is something wrong, plug in your Arduino and try to uninstall its COM port from Device Manager, then unplug it, wait a few seconds and replug it again.

Comment: I uninstalled the COM port, waited a few seconds as you said and replugged it. Then I went over to the Arduino IDE and uploaded the blink again. Then the TX is high while it says "Uploading" and I still get the not in sync errors. Image: http://i.imgur.com/Kc4HltE.jpg

Comment: `Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200` What does this mean?

Comment: I look into the Serial monitor, and it prints numbers like: 1187.50 etc

Comment: Yes, your arduino is constantly sending values to your computer. try to upload a sketch to your arduino and when you see uploading to I/O board try to press the reset button.

Comment: btw, make sure that you use `AVRISP mkll` as programmer.

Comment: I am using AVRISP mkll and tried reseting once I upload. No difference. Image: http://i.imgur.com/MOpwPSe.png

Comment: Try to connect RX and TX pins of your Arduino with a wire and then plug it to your computer, then open Serial Monitor and send some string and see if you get it back?

Comment: Should I add pinMode 0 and 1 as outputs in setup? I connected a wire from RX (0) to TX (1)

Comment: No don't use any sketch, just open the Serial Monitor and see what happens?

Comment: It prints numbers on the same line. I connected a wire from 0 to 1, right?

Comment: The TX light is flashing. RX light doesn't respond.

Comment: Do you have another arduino or another chip?

Comment: No, this is the only one. I uploaded an empty sketch and now the TX is lighting constantly.

Comment: `avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
...`

Comment: Are there other solutions? I think the chip needs to be reprogrammed..

Comment: I feel the same, you either need another arduino to use it as ISP programmer or an AVR programmer.

Comment: I read somewhere else that one got it to work by changing the baud rate. Where do I change the baud rate? Did he just send a command in the serial monitor? `avrdude.exe -v -P COM3 -c arduino -p atmega328p -b57600 ...`

Comment: Before dealing with avrdude, did you try to change the usb cable? use a short one.

Comment: Also, try Tools->Programmer->AVR ISP. then upload blink sketch.

Comment: The solution that involved dealing with avrdude is for arduino clone boards based on CH340 chip. You arduino is obviously a genuine one.

Comment: Yes, mine is 100% genuine. I'll try the AVR ISP. And yes, I've tried 2 cables but none of them worked. They are long though.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work by changing to AVR ISP.

Comment: If you can get an AVR programmer that would solve your problem, it will use SPI interface to program the chip rather than the UART (Serial interface)

Comment: I tried another Arduino today and that one worked. So I guess the other Arduino board's chip has to be reprogrammed. Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: Yes I think so, you may use that Arduino to reprogram yours.

Comment: You probably could try use **Old bootloader** option in the arduino IDE upload configuration

Answer (score 0):

You should re-burn the bootloader. If you have another uno, you can burn bootloader [here](https://tutorial.cytron.io/2015/02/04/using-isp-burn-bootloader-arduino/)